# Loss/Risk function for sci-kit learn's naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was wondering if it somehow possible to define a loss function to the Naive Bayes classifier in scikit-learn. For example, let's assume that we are interested in spam vs. ham classification. In this context, such a loss function would be useful to lower the False positive rate (i.e., classifying ham as spam, which is "worse" than classifying spam as ham)

For simplicity, I have an example using random data from Gaussian [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/stat_pattern_class/supervised/parametric/5_stat_superv_parametric.ipynb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loss function of naive Bayes is always the negative joint log-likelihood, -log *p*(*X*, *Y*). This choice of loss function, under the naive Bayes assumption of feature independence, makes naive Bayes fast: maximum-likelihood training can be done by performing one matrix multiplication and a few sums. All other loss functions that I can think of would bring you into iterative optimization land.

Regarding your actual problem: you can try to adjust the learner parameters with [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) using `scoring='precision'` or a custom scoring function based on `sklearn.metric.fbeta_score` or `roc_auc_score`. I'm not sure if that will a lot in naive Bayes, though, so you may want to switch to logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I guess I will do some hyperparameter tuning via GridSearch on the smoothening parameter and the priors then. Thanks!